# Make session available outside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I access `session` from a lib class outside my controller? Is that possible?

What I want to do is a route constraint. I could do it with a filter at my application controller, but I think doing this in a separated class makes my code more compact and clean.

Comment: This might be a useful and interesting read: http://m.onkey.org/how-to-access-session-cookies-params-request-in-model

Comment: If the constraint is simple enough you can do it in routes.rb :)

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d yes.. with lambda; But I need to check some data stored on the session in order to allow the access or not.